# Positioning Issue in FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Excuse the simple question, the issue i'm having maybe due to lack of sleep. I am having a positioning problem in my firefox browser. [click here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/jukebox/dancers.php) for some reason the bottom row of images are not displaying correctly in FF however they are in Chrome. Does anyone know what's causing this issue, i'll like to know this for future reference..

Comment: 1. What are you expecting? 2. What have you tried?

Comment: For the positioning of the images to match the way it is in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use clearfix - clear the floats.

Clear the floats - by this I mean [**Quirks Help**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you don't have profile-box defined anywhere in your CSS?  When I look in both Firefox and Chrome, the computed width of each profile-box is 770px, which is probably part of the problem since that appears to be the full width of the container.  Properly defining the width/height of the profile-box should solve your problem.